# Creating sql server db backup

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to create a database backup and I'm pretty new to this.

I've created the .bak file already.

Do I need to backup the mdf and ldf files too?

Comment: You've done it! Time for the weekend.

Comment: You'll probably want to keep [Hallengren's Backup Script](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) handy if you're new to this. You didn't elaborate on what kind of backup you did, the mode of the DB, etc but it's a good reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, *.bak file will be enough, as per MS instructions:

**B. Full back up to disk to non-default location**

In this example the Sales database will be backed up to disk at E:\MSSQL\BAK. Previous back ups of Sales have been taken.

- List item
- In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine and then expand that instance.
- Expand Databases, right-click Sales, point to Tasks, and then click Back Up....
- On the General page in the Destination section select Disk from the Back up to: drop-down list.
- Click Remove until all existing backup files have been removed.
- Click Add and the Select Backup Destination dialog box will open.
- Enter E:\MSSQL\BAK\Sales_20160801.bak in the file name text box.
- Click OK.
- Click OK.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-a-full-database-backup-sql-server

But still, if you are not happy to do all this by hands and if you a looking to backup your data in the cloud storage, there will be better to use some backup software (CloudBerry, Veam etc.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all above answers just want to highlight key things so you'll be more familiar with what you've done and what are your next steps (in case of bad things happen to your DBs/tables).

SQL Server databases use two files - an **MDF** file, known as the primary database file, which contains the schema and data, and a **LDF** file, which contains the logs. A database may also use secondary database file, which normally uses a **NDF** extension (afaik: mdf = main data file, ndf = next data file, ldf = log data file), might be wrong in some of the words.

Now, **BAK** files are full database backup files and **TRN** transaction log backup files. Transaction logs with full backup can be used for rolling back your DBs state to certain point in time. Among with [different](http://cloudberrylab.com/sql) products available in the internet, BAK file can be prepared natively using SQL server utilities (I am guessing you've done this way).

So you have full, you are saved.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to backup the database files, one is to have a copy of the .bak files and restore them using the SQL SMS, but this doesn't support point in tine restores and may have consistency issues in the restored database.
The .bak files can be easily backed up by automated PowerShell scripts.
Another way is to backup the live data files i.e ldf,mdf,ndf using a backup agent which ensures that the data can be restored in point time and the consistency is also maintained.
The data files can be backed up conveniently using easy software like cloudberry, Acronis and even using MS System centre data protection manager.

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is sufficient for a back up. It is worth noting that you can stop the database, detach the MDF file, and move that to a new instance and start up the database again. This is just as efficient as a back up if dealing with small databases.

Comment: Thanks! That was more simple than I thought! I didn't know that the .bak file was enough. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you had better backup all the files. But if you are new and not sure about the whole backup process I would recommend to use some third-party backup tools that are able to deal with databases e.g.cloudberry or Unitrends or Asgira.